# JENKINS how to deploy artifacts to maven repo

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

I use jenkins 1.500 and I looking for plugin that will provide possibility to deploy artifacts to maven repository, in previuos version of jenkins it was possible in post build actions using maven-plugin but for now that option dissappear...

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952832/235179).

You can add a "Post-build Actions" to "Deploy artifacts to Maven Repository" (the [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) will need to be installed). Then click "Advanced" and set your Repository URL to something appropriate (`http://yourserver:8082/nexus/content/repositories/releases/`) and set Repository ID to the server in your `settings.xml` that contains the authentication necessary, such as `my-releases` or whatever.

Comment: @JBCP It's part of the "Maven Integration plugin"

Comment: I cannot find "Maven Integration Plugin" is it outdated?

Comment: My install lists it as part of the "Maven Integration Plugin" but links to the [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Isn't running the `deploy` phase of your project what you are looking for?

Comment: I need after jenkins build deploy artifacts on nexus

Comment: The maven deploy phase always happens after the build which could be the package phase

Comment: I'm lost. If your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` is properly configured with your nexus server, then running `mvn deploy` be it on jenkisn or the command line, will deploy the artifacts in your nexus server

Comment: I don't know if this is what the OP is getting at, but it's nice to use your CI server to deploy your artifacts in a way that your project (pom.xml) won't need to know the location of your artifact repo.

Comment: yes and no.  relying on custom deploy logic in the pom is a mixed blessing.  if the pom has no deployment info, it would be nice to have a jenkins extension in the build process that privatizes and hides the deploy info from the source code

Comment: mvn deploy isn't atomic for multimodule projects. You could have a build that fails at 14/26 and you'd have 14 modules deployed out of what is actually a failed build. That will cause inconsistencies in your artifact repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform this activity using "Jenkins promoted builds plugin". Useful when I want to deploy the artifacts after regression tests are successful. The build is promoted when the regression tests are completed, and then we can add an action to deploy the artifacts to the Maven repo.

Note: To use this feature you shouldn't deactivate the automatic artifact archiving.