# Jenkins parameter passed to other plugins

Tags: jenkins, parameter-passing

Is there a way to change a job configuration in jenkins depending on passed parameters?

I am using **Artifact Promotion Plugin** to promote artifacts on Nexus. I added a build step to use this plugin and I have to fill in some properties :

- Artifact Group, Id, Version, Packaging
- Source Repository URL
- Username for source repository
- Password for source repository
- Target Repository URL
- Username for target repository
- Password for target repository

I want to parameterize the username and password for the source and target repository so that each time someone launch the build in Jenkins, he has to put his/her username and password as build parameters

I tried with **Parameterized plugin**, but it seems that the parameters defined by this plugin can only be accessed by batch and shell scripts and can not be used by other plugins.

(Needless to say, I don't want any password stored in xml files or displayed by console)

**Thanks**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069350/how-can-you-deploy-a-specific-artifact-from-jenkins-into-nexus   check whether it is helpful for you

Comment: This seems like a "hack" solution that might work in my case if I combine it with the "mask passwords plugin". I'll try it and tell you the result

Comment: yeah.. or else you can redirect only that login command (which contains password)output to null file(dont display it in standard output. it could be a very simple fix

Comment: <cmd>./script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1  for that command   then reset  back to standard output.. its just a tweak. then you get time to invest on plugins