# Nexus Artifacts Uploading

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gitlab, nexus

How to upload artifacts to nexus with auto generating the version by using jenkins shell? I am using this script and I want to generate the version automatically when artifact uploading.

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file \
          -DgroupId= \
          -DartifactId= \
          -Dversion=  \
          -DgeneratePom= \
          -Dpackaging= \
          -DrepositoryId= \
          -Durl= \
          -Dfile=
```

Comment: how your target version should be like ? can it be based on $BUILD_NUMBER variable ?

Comment: target version is 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Can I take it from pom.xml? I am new to these things.                                                                          
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: yes, you can get it from pom.xml using the maven help plugin.
run it in jenkins execute shell before deploy and it will return the version, and use it in deploy
`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version`

Comment: `mvn --quite org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.0.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version`

Comment: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -e '^[^\[]'` Given script works fine and this also works. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` variable in your Jenkins pipeline to specify the artifact version.

To do this there are few options:

1. If you want to publish artifacts to Nexus during `mvn deploy`, then you can use `${revision}` parameter in `pom.xml` file.
   To do this, you need to put this variable into `<version>` tag. E.g., `<version>1.0-${revision}</version>`
   and then provide it to the maven command in Jenkins pipeline: `mvn deploy -Drevision=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`.
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53538618/10721592) answer for details.
2. Also you can use **Nexus Jenkins Plugin** to upload artifacts to nexus and specify the artifact version using `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` variable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536998/10721592) for details.