# Specify version when deploying to nexus from maven

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, nexus, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've forked [Confluent's Kafka Connect HDFS writer](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs)  and now I'd like to deploy a version of this jar to my local Nexus.

`mvn clean deploy` Works like a charm and deploys the jar.

`https://[nexus]/repository/releases/io/confluent/kafka-connect-hdfs/5.0.0/kafka-connect-hdfs-5.0.0.jar`

So far so good, but to make a distinction between the confluent versions and my own deployment I'd like to change the version of the build to something like `5.0.0-1` or so (preferably the tag name when pushed, but that's step 2)

The pom.xml is basically the same as the [5.0.0-post](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/blob/5.0.0-post/pom.xml) release, but here the most important parts:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-storage-common-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kafka-connect-hdfs</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>kafka-connect-hdfs</name>
    <organization>
        <name>Confluent, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://confluent.io</url>
    </organization>
    <url>http://confluent.io</url>
    <description>
        A Kafka Connect HDFS connector for copying data between Kafka and Hadoop HDFS.
    </description>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-storage-common</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-storage-core</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <artifactId>kafka-connect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
...
```

So first I added `<version>` tags to the pom.xml, but it started using that as the default for all `confluent.version` and complained that it couldn't find for example: `https://[nexus]/repository/releases/io/confluent/kafka-connect-storage-hive/5.0.0-1/kafka-connect-storage-hive-5.0.0-1.pom`

Next I tried the [versions plugin from maven](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html)
`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=5.0.0-1 clean deploy`

But that complained about the parent:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set (default-cli) on project kafka-connect-hdfs: Project version is inherited from parent. -> [Help 1]

I don't even care if the version is 5.0.0 in the code, I just wat to deploy  to a different version in our artifactory.

I'm not a maven expert, so maybe I'm missing some very basic clue, but all help is welcome.

Comment: Where is confluent.version defined? What is its definition?

Comment: I actually don't know. I'm assuming that the `kafka-connect-maven-plugin` is doing some magic in this area, because I cannot find a reference in this project.

Comment: When I used extensive debugging it all of a sudden has this line `[DEBUG] properties used {docker.upstream-registry=placeholder/, ... confluent.version=5.0.0, avro.version=1.8.1, java.vm.info=mixed mode, ...
`

Comment: Personally, I just use our existing Nexus repos, but have `<artifactId>kafka-connect-hdfs</artifactId><scope>provided</scope><version>5.0.0</version>`, then just extend whatever code I need... Then, if you put that built JAR into the `kafka-connect-storage-hdfs` folder, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there were some good suggestions, but in the end the one thing that worked best for me in our setup was to use the `deploy:deploy-file` command for maven.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
-Dfile=target/kafka-connect-hdfs-5.0.0.jar \
-DrepositoryId=[nexus id] \
-Durl=[nexus url] \
-Dversion=$TAG \
-DgroupId=io.confluent \
-DartifactId=kafka-connect-hdfs
```

The major downside was that I had to respecify parameters that were already present in the pom.xml (`artifactId`, `groupId`, ect), but it works, and that's what counts :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the version with `${revision}` parameter.

To do this, you need to add `<version>` tag with this variable in pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>kafka-connect-hdfs</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0-${revision}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And then provide it to the maven command. E.g.,
`mvn clean package -Drevision=01` will generate `kafka-connect-hdfs-5.0.0-01.jar` file.

Comment: Thanks biruk1230, I've actually tried this (sorry for not mentioning) but I ran into the same issues

Comment: That's strange. Did you try to add this code to your pom.xml (under the **<build>** section)?

    `<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>`