# My artifactory upload stage to nexus fails whenever i change my pom version in pom file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I am using declrative pipeline and whenever I change my pom version my artifactory upload stage to nexus fails. For example: if my snapshot version is `0.3`, my build is successful. If change my snapshot version as `0.4` in my pom file and try to create the same build, the build fails at upload artifactory stage. So my question is each time we have to update both jenkins file and pom file for the build to work properly ? is there a declarative way where version is getting incremented by itself?

```
stage('Upload Artifacts') {
    steps {
        nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [[artifactId: 'com.lfx', classifier: 'debug', file: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Pipeline/target/common-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar', type: 'jar']], credentialsId: 'f97e3ef5-19ca-4903-b2c5-74a7821062de', groupId: 'LLL', nexusUrl: 'localhost:8081/', nexusVersion: 'nexus3', protocol: 'http', repository: 'LLLTEST', version: '0.4-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

Error:

> java.io.IOException: common-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar file doesn't exists
>       at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution.run(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:242)
>       at sp.sd.nexusartifactuploader.steps.NexusArtifactUploaderStep$Execution.run(NexusArtifactUploaderStep.java:217)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>       at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build fails because you're specified the hardcoded value for `nexusArtifactUploader` file parameter (and the same for version parameter):

```
file: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Pipeline/target/common-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

You need to use dynamic version instead, like in [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nexus-artifact-uploader-plugin) example:

```
nexusArtifactUploader(
    nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
    protocol: 'http',
    nexusUrl: 'my.nexus.address',
    groupId: 'com.example',
    version: version,
    repository: 'RepositoryName',
    credentialsId: 'CredentialsId',
    artifacts: [
        [artifactId: projectName,
         classifier: '',
         file: 'my-service-' + version + '.jar',
         type: 'jar']
    ]
 )
```

Also you can use [Nexus Platform Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-jenkins-plugin), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536998/10721592) answer for example . `${pom.version}` is used there and it's read right from `pom.xml` file.

So you don't need to increment or pass version manually, just use command:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
```

And then you can specify your file like:

```
"target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}"
```

Also, there is another way to change your artifact version automatically - by specifying it as `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` in your Jenkins pipeline and then pass it as a parameter to `mvn` command. E.g., like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539337/10721592) answer.

Comment: Thanks biruk1230 for your suggestion. I modified my jenkinsfile as you suggested. But still i feel that this way is also hard coded. cos i am declaring variable like def version = '0.3-SNAPSHOT'. which means only 0.3 version snapshot will be pushed to artifacts stage and if change the version to 0.4, i dont think so it will work(since the version is hard coded). i was looking a dynamic way to change my version. I am yet to try the second method which you suggested to read from pom file. will check and update

Comment: Yes, you can change your version dynamically by reading `pom.xml` with that command that I provided: `def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'`. It should work for both **Nexus Artifact Uploader** and **Nexus Platform** plugins as well.
Also, there is another method to specify the artifact version - passing it to `mvn` command in your Jenkinsfile. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539337/10721592) answer for details.

Comment: I am getting this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nexus Configuration localhost:8081/ not found.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)

Comment: my jenkins file stage script {
    def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
    nexusPublisher nexusInstanceId: 'localhost:8081/', \
    nexusRepositoryId: 'LLLTEST', \
    packages: [[$class: 'MavenPackage', \
    mavenAssetList: [[classifier: '', extension: '', filePath: "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}"]], \
    mavenCoordinate: [artifactId: "${pom.artifactId}", \
    groupId: "${pom.groupId}", \
    packaging: "${pom.packaging}", \
    version: "${pom.version}"]]]
    }

Comment: As you've already had configured `nexusArtifactUploader` build, try to use that instead of `nexusPublisher`, but provide `def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml' ` command before `nexusArtifactUploader` command.
However, if you want to use **Nexus Publisher** plugin, you need to add Nexus Repository Manager Server in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` page and there specify a unique string ID of your server. See details [here](https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-and-continuous-integration/nexus-platform-plugin-for-jenkins#NexusPlatformPluginforJenkins-RepositoryManager2Integration).