# Is there way to increment the version automatically which building the job through jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Whenever I run my jenkins build I want my snapshot version to be auto incremented. I do understand there are several plugins to them, just trying to understand is there a way to achieve this without any pluggins?

Comment: I recommend to read this: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change your artifact version automatically - by specifying it as `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` (for example) in your Jenkins pipeline and then pass it as a `{revision}` parameter to `mvn` command. To do this, you need to put this `{revision}` variable into `<version>` tag like following

```
<version>${revision}</version>
```

and then provide it to the maven command in Jenkins pipeline:

```
mvn deploy -Drevision=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539337/10721592) answer (1st option) for details.

Note: as [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) pointed out, you have to use the **flatten-maven-plugin**, otherwise there could be some issues, see details in [this](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) article. (However, in my case for simple maven project there were no such problems, so I didn't use that plugin, only `revision` parameter)

Comment: Why not? From that article you can see that if you're using a command like `mvn deploy -Drevision=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`, then it will work correctly. I think that if you're using automated builds in Jenkins, then it will not be a problem to add `-Drevision=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` argument. And I don't see better option for auto incrementing version in Jenkins build without adding a parameter to `mvn` command.

Comment: You have not read until the end of the documentation (flatten-maven-plugin). If you use your setup you resulting pom files will be errornous..means you can't consume them..!! (See here: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Comment: As I understand, it's only for multi module projects, for simple project all is fine (I already tried that). Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Not sure, I've used `revision` parameter without flatten-maven-plugin, and all was working perfectly without any issues. Anyway, added your info above, thanks!

Comment: thanks @biruk1230 .. i tried using revision and ran into some errors

Answer (score -1):

You can use [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html)

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
```

The Goal “build-helper:parse-version” provides parse fragments of the actual version in the pom.xml and calculates also the incremented fragments of the version:
Use can use this vars to setup new version

```
parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion
parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion
parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion
```

Comment: @Tirex- and how do i call that in jenkins file ?