# How to trigger a pipeline execution in QA environment?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

Jenkins has an option to trigger a pipeline(in Dev or Prod) for every commit in a specific Git branch.

In continuation with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174394/jenkins-how-many-ci-cd-pipelines-for-a-release/54178144?noredirect=1#comment95187005_54178144), that talks about a pipeline in QA environment to execute(smoke/regression/...) on every new artifact generated by Dev pipeline in Nexus(say).

---

1) 
For every new artifact(say `product-x.y-snapshot.jar` in Nexus) generated in Dev pipeline, What is the option in Jenkins that is used to trigger a QA pipeline execution? Mechanics of using Jenkins...

2)
Using Jenkins pipeline(QA env), What technology is used to deploy `product-x.y-snapshot.jar` in a VM and invoke QA tests(written in python)? and provide the test results.

Comment: 1) build step 2) depends, how do you run tests locally?

Comment: @hakamairi am sorry.. we run tests on slave jenkins server. So yess.. locally to a jenkins server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to automate this procedure and run QA pipeline only if new tag is created then you can use GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket webhooks.

2) You can use [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) (**declarative** or more advanced **scripted** pipeline syntax) to run tests on your agent directly. To downloading artifacts for testing, you can use something like [Repository Connector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin) or [this](https://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/downloading-artifacts-from-nexus-with-bash/) scripted solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186818/discussion-on-answer-by-biruk1230-how-to-trigger-a-pipeline-execution-in-qa-envi).