# How to archive all the build versions (Artifacts) in target folder

Tags: jenkins

Each time i generate my build through jenkins, my existing jar file in the target folder is overwritten by maven. For example: i have a existing version of 1.0 in jenkins target folder, now if i create a new build with version 1.1, the previous version in my target folder gets overwritten.

I don't want that to happen, i want to archive all the versions (because we might provide some of the old features to certain set of customers). i am just trying to understand is there way to do this in jenkins pipeline. I don't prefer plugins, it would be nice to do it declarative way using jenkins file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not the best solution to store your artifacts just in target folder without any copying to other place. Usually all needed build artifacts are stored in [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) repositories (of course, you can copy them to some local directory also). You can do that in pipeline Jenkinsfile as well, but you still require to install needed plugin. For example, for publishing artifacts to Nexus repo, you can use [Nexus Platform Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-jenkins-plugin), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536998/10721592) answer for details.

About overwriting your target folder, I'm not sure if it's cleaned by Jenkins by default. To clean workspace, you need to specify `Discard old builds` option in job configuration first.

Seems to be that you just execute `mvn clean ...` command, that's why target folder is cleaned, so I would recommend to check that first.