# Jenkins Maven Nexus, how to learn it?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, devops

TASK: I was charged to make/test CI pipeline for any Java (Maven preferably) sources in Jenkins (all Devops tools must be in Docker containers) . I need to do basic stages :

- 1) Get source from github - done (I did by creating task in Jenkins
  and used example java app from some github repo)
- 2) Build in Maven - done
- 3) Make Junit tests - done
- 4) Push artifacts ( .war file probably) to Nexus 3 repository - need
  to solve

HOW I tried to SOLVE: I've found the docker-ci-tool-stack ( "Devops-ready" platform: Jenkins, SonarQube, Nexus, GitLab) , so I've just used it for my purpose (here it is https://github.com/marcelbirkner/docker-ci-tool-stack) First I've tried to understand building app example from that repo, but stuck in Groove DSL scripts. After I've been trying look some tutorials, documents on integration: Jenkins , Maven and Nexus, but it's incomprehensible for me. I agree, that I should own each tool separately and after combine it together (and work in other place probably) , but I've a terms from by boss... What should I do?
I passed some courses in Linux Academy for Git, Docker and Jenkins, but I still feel really raw in practice that DevOps (CI/CD),
 Thank you.

Comment: Simple answer to your question: Simply use the tools and after a long time you know how they work and how to use them...

Comment: Do you have development experience?

Comment: as @khmarbaise said, practice is the only way. You have to work with each tool. Start with some hello world, try to learn each one separately. Through basic.

Here's a sample on deploying to nexus - try it first from command line.
Jenkins just executes these commands.

http://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you. The problem I haven't neither dev experience nor time for each tool, because my teamlead think I don't need deep learn each separately and should to learn on the fly by tutorials and searching... :(

Comment: @Vijay thank you. I agree with you, it right direction.

Comment: @LocalOps I have to say you won't really learn them on the fly nor understand them really which is fundamentally needed to use them efficiently. Your teamlead has not understood what DevOps etc. means nor realized the fundamental ideas behind that. If you don't have time you will never get it...cause that's thing which absolutely necessary to learn. Don't get me wrong but things like: `becoming a professional within 21 days` does not work(I'm working for 30 years their and learning continuously). Also you need to do some development in Java otherwise you won't understand the concepts.

Comment: @khmarbaise I absolutely agree with you, thank you. I've just post my question only to verify/prove my opinion about, so exactly the same. I've told to him, but he doesn't realize the complexity. I really don't like these experiments... Thank you for your time and opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding the distributionManagement section to your pom.xml file.

```
<project ...>

  ...

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://your-host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <url>http://your-host:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And add in Jenkins job to Maven(mvn) section:

```
deploy
```

**Briefly:**

- [Infrastructure with maven, Jenkins, Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950346/infrastructure-with-maven-jenkins-nexus)

**More details here:**

- http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/02/08/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts/
- http://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try other way. which i can say non maven way and it is like using nexus artifact uploader plugin . If you are use jenkins pipeline then there step for it in syntax generator. Refer the images

[here groupid and version can be any value i chose this random values in repository pass the name of repo that you created in nexus dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gffpg.png)wH.png
[artifactid and classifier can be any value. in the type write war if its war file , jar if its jar or zip if its zip file; Then in File section pass the path of war file which was created after creating the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGd)
[When you click generate buld you will get this step script just paste it after the step where war file has been build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcqtm.png)